# Finding relation between variants

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition

There are certain programs which each have certain features. There is also a feature vector which is the Union of all the features. I have modeled the vector of features as following.

1 - the feature is present in the feature vector

0 - the feature is absent in the feature vector.

I have to find a relation between the following variants

10001110

10110101

10010111

10101100

10011101

Here the relation in all the programs is that the 0,1 and 5 positions do not change i.e., the features they represent, tend to continue.
Given a large data set as this are there any Machine Learning/Data Mining approaches that can find the relation between them.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [affinity analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_analysis), e.g., as used in [market basket analysis](http://snowplowanalytics.com/analytics/recipes/catalog-analytics/market-basket-analysis-identifying-products-that-sell-well-together.html).

Suppose each vector of yours is a shopping bag checked out by a customer, and each column is a product. Then market-basket analysis will find stuff like:

- Buying milk + eggs => buying butter
- Most by bread

The application to your problem seems natural.